# modsecurity unable to retrieve collection error

Tags: apache-2.2

```
    [Sat Jul 31 17:22:20 2010] [error] [client ::1] ModSecurity: Unable to retrieve collection (name "global", key "global"). Use SecDataDir to define data directory first. [hostname "localhost"] [uri "/ajaxterm"] [unique_id "TFQOdH8AAAEAAE-nKKsAAAAG"]
[Sat Jul 31 17:22:20 2010] [error] [client ::1] ModSecurity: Unable to retrieve collection (name "ip", key "::1"). Use SecDataDir to define data directory first. [hostname "localhost"] [uri "/ajaxterm"] [unique_id "TFQOdH8AAAEAAE-nKKsAAAAG"]
[Sat Jul 31 17:22:20 2010] [error] [client ::1] ModSecurity: Unable to retrieve collection (name "global", key "global"). Use SecDataDir to define data directory first. [hostname "localhost"] [uri "/u"] [unique_id "TFQOdH8AAAEAAE-oKZQAAAAH"]
[Sat Jul 31 17:22:20 2010] [error] [client ::1] ModSecurity: Unable to retrieve collection (name "ip", key "::1"). Use SecDataDir to define data directory first. [hostname "localhost"] [uri "/u"] [unique_id "TFQOdH8AAAEAAE-oKZQAAAAH"]
```

Does does these error mean?

Comment: apparently the Apache mod_security file is looking for an entry
SecDataDir /var/asl/data/msa
in the /etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/modsecurity_crs_10_config.conf file.

HTH somebody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently the Apache mod_security file is looking for an entry SecDataDir /var/asl/data/msa in the /etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/modsecurity_crs_10_config.conf file. HTH somebody –

Comment: It's just looking for a Directory to use to store data in! /var/asl/data/ is actually referring to Atomic Secured Linux's security packages, as far as I can determine after a really quick look :)